# An argument for 'invokeMiddleware' was not provided

Tags: typescript, loopback4

I got this error while implementing loopback4 authentication.

```
    constructor (
    // ---- ADD THIS LINE ------
    @inject(AuthenticationBindings.AUTH_ACTION)
    protected authenticateRequest: AuthenticateFn,
    ) {
       super(authenticateRequest);
    }
```

Comment: More details needed - where is this being added to? What part of Auth are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @RifaAchrinza I'm trying to implement user authentication using this link https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Authentication-tutorial.html#step-4-protect-the-todo-apis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*This answer was taken from the community Slack channel*

As per-[the documentation](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Authentication-tutorial.html#step-2-add-authenticate-action) ([permalink](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/blame/8ca03f68b16f5a16e205837a6cb8c3616bce4b32/docs/site/tutorials/authentication/Authentication-Tutorial.md#L119)), modifying `src/sequence.ts` is only meant for the [now-deprecated Action-based Sequences](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/REST-action-sequence.html), and not required for [Middleware-based Sequences](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/REST-middleware-sequence.html) which are used by default on newly-generated LoopBack 4 projects.

### How to identify the "sequence type"

The class signature will hint at which sequence type is being used:

```js
// Action-based sequence
class MySequence extends DefaultSequence {/* ... */}

// Middleware-based Sequence
class MySequence extends MiddlewareSequence {/* ... */}
```